# Android webview displays blank page when I call loadDataWithBaseUrl

Tags: android, webview

I have got html data from web API，then I use `loadDataWithBaseUrl` to display but sometimes it displays a blank page, then I click the screen, it works, and displays the data. I have called `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`. I think it maybe WebView's rendering problem. Can anyone solve the problem?

I have found out that the problem is caused by my phone. When I use VM, it works well.

Comment: can you post sample code ? Chrome debugging is good way to see any javascript console errors https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have found the problem,it' caused by my phone.when i use VM ,it works well.